# Diff between dates calculates incorrect

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two `dateTime` fields and I am trying to get the difference between them. However my results are coming out less than they should. I have looked at examples and the code seems fine.

```
    $entryTime = new \DateTime($journalEntry->entry_date_time->toTimeString());
    $closeTime = new \DateTime($journalEntry->close_date_time->toTimeString());
    $interval = $entryTime->diff($closeTime);

    debug($journalEntry->entry_date_time);
    debug($journalEntry->close_date_time);
    echo $interval->format('%d days %h hours %m minutes');
```

I am getting 0 days 11 hours 0 minutes

```
/src/Controller/JournalEntriesController.php (line 145)
object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

    'time' => '2020-09-05 07:49:04.000000+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}
/src/Controller/JournalEntriesController.php (line 146)
object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

    'time' => '2020-09-07 19:36:53.000000+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}
```

Comment: So what do you actually want to diff, date _and_ time, or only the time? Because your code does the latter, and it's unclear from your question what you actually want. Also note that `%m` is not minutes, but months, minutes is `%i`.

Comment: Yes I would like to get both date and time: number of days, hours and minutes between the two times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to diff date *and* time, then there's no reason to create new `DateTime` objects, especially not from a time-only string, which would result in diffing only the time.

Simply diff the instances that you already have, they extend from `\DateTime` and `\DateTimeImmutable` respectively:

```php
$interval = $journalEntry->entry_date_time->diff($journalEntry->close_date_time);
echo $interval->format('%d days %h hours %i minutes');
```

and as mentioned in the comments, `m` is for months, [**the pattern character**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#refsect1-dateinterval.format-parameters) for minutes is `i`.

CakePHP's datetime objects also provide additional diffing functionality for obtaining specific units (`diffInHours()`, `diffInMinutes()`, etc) or human readable formats (`diffForHumans()`).

See also

- **[Chronos Cookbook > Chronos > Generating Differences](https://book.cakephp.org/chronos/2/en/index.html#generating-differences)**
- **[Chronos API > \Cake\Chronos\Traits\DifferenceTrait](https://api.cakephp.org/chronos/2.x/trait-Cake.Chronos.Traits.DifferenceTrait.html)**
- **[PHP Manual > Function Reference > Date and Time Related Extensions > Date/Time > DateInterval > DateInterval::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)**